# Icons or symbols for asymmetric (public-key) cryptography

Tags: icon, symbols, symbolism

I need some graphical representation of the elements of asymmetric (public-key) cryptography. I have not been able to find any established convention in this area, and struggle to find good candidates myself for:

- private key
- public key
- asymmetrically encrypted content

Especially grateful for successful usages in the wild, but inspiration for my own wortk is appreciated too.

These are technical concepts, but the target audience understand the distinctions, and handling them explicitly is integral to the purpose of the target application.

Padlock seems fairly established for encrypted content, so some variant on that might be a candidate. But what twist would be sufficiently distinctive, and if possible suggestive of the difference from a regular one?

Similarly, how can I distinguish the two types of keys in a way that makes it immediately clear that they are different from each other, and also easy to deduce or at least remember which is which, provided you already understand the context.

Comment: have you checked https://thenounproject.com/ ? Although I suppose it will be very difficult to find a symbol that represents clearly "asymmetrically encrypted content" as it's a very specific, very abstract concept. You might need to come up with your own.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. There and cdn.materialdesignicons.com.  I find lots of keys and locks, but only a very few explicitly concerning asymmetric encryption, and no coherent symbol-language for expressing the three concepts in a common context.